# Cannot initialize Twig

Tags: php, twig

I tried Twig on my localhost and all worked ok, but after migrating to VDS it doesnt work

```
echo 'step 1!<br>';
require_once "/var/www/Libs/Twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php";
echo 'step 2!<br>';
Twig_Autoloader::register();
echo 'step 3!<br>';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem( "/var/www/Templates" );
echo 'step 4!<br>';
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader,  array(
'cache' => "/var/www/Cache", 'auto_reload' => true, 'debug' => true));
echo 'step 5!<br>';
$twig->loadTemplate('page.tpl');
echo 'step 6!<br>';
echo $template->render();
echo $twig->render($template, array('the' => 'variables'));
echo 'step 7!<br>';
```

outputs only step 1.. step 5. no PHP errors appears (E_ALL)

Comment: You have `display_errors` enabled?  No output after `step 5` would indicate a likely fatal error.

Comment: ... like a missing closing `)` at `'auto_reload' => true, 'debug' => true,);`

Comment: Yes, they are enabled, display _errors = On in php.ini.

Comment: and it's ok with closing, I just decided to add it to code and then to add here and misspelled it here) I think that if there was something wrong with it the program ended on step 4 anyway

Comment: I thought may be the problem is with wrong path, but surely /var/www is the path of web server... I'm on VDS

Comment: Maybe. Do all those paths `/var/www/*` exist?  Is the cache directory writable if it needs to be? I have no experience with Twig, and therefore don't know conventions for debugging it.

Comment: really... my fault... there was display_errors = On, but near the end there was also display_errors = Off((